# How can I reuse function and not keep repeating it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wrote a function to hide and show a tab when clicked using JavaScript. As I am adding tabs, I also add function to perform the task. I am sure there is a way to narrow this down so I don't have to create a new function each time and reuse the one I have.

Here is my JS (https://jsfiddle.net/ehwcma6j/1/):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function showDiv() {
        var info = document.getElementById('detailInformation');
        if (info.style.display === "none") {
          info.style.display = "block";
          info.style.transition = "0.2s ease-out";
        } else {
          info.style.display = "none";
          info.style.transition = "0.2s ease-out";
        }
      }
      function showDiv2() {
        var info2 = document.getElementById('detailInformation2');
        if (info2.style.display === "none") {
          info2.style.display = "block";
          info2.style.transition = "0.2s ease-out";
        } else {
          info2.style.display = "none";
          info2.style.transition = "0.2s ease-out";
        }
      }
      function showDiv3() {
        var info3 = document.getElementById('detailInformation3');
        if (info3.style.display === "none") {
          info3.style.display = "block";
          info3.style.transition = "0.2s ease-out";
        } else {
          info3.style.display = "none";
          info3.style.transition = "0.2s ease-out";
        }
      }
      function showDiv4() {
        var info4 = document.getElementById('detailInformation4');
        if (info4.style.display === "none") {
          info4.style.display = "block";
          info4.style.transition = "0.2s ease-out";
        } else {
          info4.style.display = "none";
          info4.style.transition = "0.2s ease-out";
        }
      }
</script>
```

And here is my html:

```
<div class="block" style="text-align: center;">
  <div>
    <div style="padding: 10px 0 10px 0; float: left; width: 50%;">
      <h1>Tab 1</h1>
    </div>
      <div style="padding: 10px 0 10px 0;"><input class="button" name="answer" onclick="showDiv()" type="button" value="More information" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="answer_list" id="detailInformation" style="display: none; text-align: left; padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;">
    <p>some text</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div style="padding: 10px 0 10px 0; float: left; width: 50%;">
      <h1>Tab 2</h1>
    </div>
      <div style="padding: 10px 0 10px 0;"><input class="button" name="answer" onclick="showDiv2()" type="button" value="More information" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="answer_list" id="detailInformation2" style="display: none; text-align: left; padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;">
    <p>some text</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div style="padding: 10px 0 10px 0; float: left; width: 50%;">
      <h1>Tab 3</h1>
    </div>
      <div style="padding: 10px 0 10px 0;"><input class="button" name="answer" onclick="showDiv3()" type="button" value="More information" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="answer_list" id="detailInformation3" style="display: none; text-align: left; padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;">
    <p>some text</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div style="padding: 10px 0 10px 0; float: left; width: 50%;">
      <h1>Tab 4</h1>
    </div>
      <div style="padding: 10px 0 10px 0;"><input class="button" name="answer" onclick="showDiv4()" type="button" value="More information" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="answer_list" id="detailInformation4" style="display: none; text-align: left; padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;">
    <p>some text</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

It's probably very simple, I am only a beginner :)

Comment: Do you mean you want to eliminate all that duplicated code in your javascript? If so, look into javascript parameter passing, aka argument passing. You can boil that all down to one function, and pass the id you want as a parameter.

Comment: You need to look at each of the 3 functions and think about whats different between them, in your case its just the element id, so create a single function that accepts an id as an argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of repeating the similar function, allow it to take a parameter, e.g. the `id`

```
  function showDiv(id) {
    var info = document.getElementById(id);
    if (info.style.display === "none") {
      info.style.display = "block";
      info.style.transition = "0.2s ease-out";
    } else {
      info.style.display = "none";
      info.style.transition = "0.2s ease-out";
    }
  }
```

And for your click events, change them like this

```
onclick="showDiv('detailInformation2')"
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you for your quick response and as you were first to answer, I mark your answer as accepted. Thank you for the lesson, I will keep this in mind for future :)

Answer (score 2):

```
function showDiv(id) {
        var info = document.getElementById(id);
        if (info.style.display === "none") {
          info.style.display = "block";
          info.style.transition = "0.2s ease-out";
        } else {
          info.style.display = "none";
          info.style.transition = "0.2s ease-out";
        }
      }
//call function like

showDiv('detailInformation');
showDiv('detailInformation2');
showDiv('detailInformation3');
showDiv('detailInformation4');
```

Comment: Code dumps do not make for good answers. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 1):

I updated the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ehwcma6j/5/

You want a function that takes an id, so that you can reuse the main logic of the function:

```
function showDiv(id) {
  var info = document.getElementById(id);
  if (info.style.display === "none") {
    info.style.display = "block";
    info.style.transition = "0.2s ease-out";
  } else {
    info.style.display = "none";
    info.style.transition = "0.2s ease-out";
  }
}
```

Then in the HTML, pass the id of the div, for example:

```
<div style="padding: 10px 0 10px 0;"><input class="button" name="answer" onclick="showDiv('detailInformation2')" type="button" value="More information" /></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

      function showDiv(id) {
        var info = document.getElementById(id);
        if (info.style.display === "none") {
          info.style.display = "block";
          info.style.transition = "0.2s ease-out";
        } else {
          info.style.display = "none";
          info.style.transition = "0.2s ease-out";
        }
      }

</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="block" style="text-align: center;">
  <div>
    <div style="padding: 10px 0 10px 0; float: left; width: 50%;">
      <h1>Tab 1</h1>
    </div>
      <div style="padding: 10px 0 10px 0;"><input class="button" name="answer" onclick="showDiv('detailInformation1')" type="button" value="More information" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="answer_list" id="detailInformation" style="display: none; text-align: left; padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;">
    <p>some text</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div style="padding: 10px 0 10px 0; float: left; width: 50%;">
      <h1>Tab 2</h1>
    </div>
      <div style="padding: 10px 0 10px 0;"><input class="button" name="answer" onclick="showDiv('detailInformation2')" type="button" value="More information" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="answer_list" id="detailInformation2" style="display: none; text-align: left; padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;">
    <p>some text</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div style="padding: 10px 0 10px 0; float: left; width: 50%;">
      <h1>Tab 3</h1>
    </div>
      <div style="padding: 10px 0 10px 0;"><input class="button" name="answer" onclick="showDiv('detailInformation3')" type="button" value="More information" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="answer_list" id="detailInformation3" style="display: none; text-align: left; padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;">
    <p>some text</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div style="padding: 10px 0 10px 0; float: left; width: 50%;">
      <h1>Tab 4</h1>
    </div>
      <div style="padding: 10px 0 10px 0;"><input class="button" name="answer" onclick="showDiv('detailInformation4')" type="button" value="More information" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="answer_list" id="detailInformation4" style="display: none; text-align: left; padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;">
    <p>some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```